# HTML::FormHandler render field without label

Tags: perl, webforms, template-toolkit

With a HTML::FormHandler formular I want to render only the field part of an form field.

```
<div>
  my label [% form.field('name').render %] 
</div>
```

This renders the field and a label.

Answer (score 3):

I see in the code that the renderer checks for:

```
$self->has_flag('no_render_label')
```

so you need to set this flag. 
How it is done? I can only make a guess.

you did not specify which widget you are using, and if I understand it right, you should extend him and create your own widget.

```
package HTML::FormHandler::Field::Checkbox::NoLabel;
use HTML::FormHandler::Moose;
extends 'HTML::FormHandler::Field::Checkbox';
our $VERSION = '0.01';

has '+no_render_label' => ( default => 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

For future searchers:

You can set the `do_label` attribute when you define your field in the form class.

```
has_field 'name' => (
    type => 'Text'
    do_label => 0,
);
```

Source: [HTML::FormHandler field attribute reference](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aFormHandler%3a%3aManual%3a%3aReference#Field-rendering)

Answer (score 0):

I've found an another way in the manual of HFH.

```
package Test::Form;
use HTML::FormHandler::Moose;
extends 'HTML::FormHandler';

has '+name' => ( default => 'testform' );
has '+widget_wrapper' => ( default => 'None' );
has '+auto_fieldset' => ( default => 0 );
has_field 'foo';
```